# PercentFrameLayout as an item in Recycler view not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-percent-layout

I'm using the `PercentFrameLayout` as an item in `RecyclerView` below is my layout. `PercentFrameLayout` is not appearing. It's not showing up.

Anything I'm missing here..?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_heightPercent="12%"
        android:background="@drawable/placeholder_image"/>
</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

When you use `layout_heightPercent`, you are asking for a percentage of the space allotted to the `PercentFrameLayout` - i.e., if the `PercentFrameLayout` had a height of `100dp`, a child view with a `layout_heightPercent="12%"` would be given `12dp`. As your `PercentFrameLayout` has no other children and is `wrap_content`, there's no clear indication what 12% of an unspecified value is, leading to no space being allocated at all.

If you're trying to set the size of the view as a percentage of the total screen size or of the total visible height available to the `RecyclerView`, you'll have to do that elsewhere, ideally as a subclass of `LinearLayoutManager` as that is what is controlling the height of individual elements.

Comment: Just a note. 12% of 120dp is 14,4dp.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Tried as u said. PercentFrameLayout to use height match_parent and its child imageview layout_heightPercent="12%" The image view is not showing :( I am trying to provide 12% of screen height not the 12% of recycler view. Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: @AmjedBaig - `match_parent` won't work either because the `RecyclerView` is attempting to be as small as possible, so it is laying out each component with an unspecified max height (remember, they scroll). Again, you're trying to do 12% of an unspecified number.

As I mentioned in the second paragraph, you cannot use this approach at all if you want items to take up a percentage of the screen size. You'll have to set the items height manually after [getting the screen dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/1676363)

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake : I was doing that previously(as mentioned by you above, in the recycler adapter while binding the item) I thought with layout_heightPercent I can do it more gracefully. thanks for the help.